# Upper Bound on $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{1 + X}]$ where $\mathbb{E}[X] = a$ and $0<<1$

Tags: probability, bounds, tail-bound

$$ is a positive random variable (potentially unbounded) with $0 \le \mathbb{E}[X] = a < 1$.

Since $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is a convex function, we can use Jensen's inequality to derive a lower bound:
$\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{1 + X}] \ge \frac{1}{1 + \mathbb{E}[X]} = \frac{1}{1 + a}$.

Is it possible to derive an upper bound?

A trivial upper bound would be 1 just because $X$ is positive. Can we derive an upper bound that involves $a$ or at least more information about $X$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As shown by @jblood94, one can not improve on the trivial upper bound
in the most general case. Yet the following inequality holds for $x \geq 0$
$$
   \frac{1}{1 + x} \: 
   \leqslant \:1 - x + x^2.
$$
Then substituting $x$ by $X$ and taking the expectation
$$
  \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{1 + X}\right] \leqslant 1 - a + \mathbb{E}[X^2],
$$
so, if the variance of $X$ - or equivalently, $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ - is
known along with the expectation, an upper bound results.

Comment: Note, in addition, that $\mathbb{E}[X^2] \leq a$, as it is maximized for a Bernoulli distribution with probability parameter $p=a$.  So your clever approach also gives $1$ as the least upper bound in the unknown variance case.

Answer (score 6):

$\mathbb{E}\big[\frac{1}{1+X}\big]\le1$ is the best you can do.

For example, consider the following PMF:

$$p_X(x) = \begin{cases}
1-\tau, & x=\tau \\
\tau, & x=\frac{\beta}{\tau}-1
\end{cases}$$

with $\tau<\beta<1+\tau^2$.

$$a=\mathbb{E}[X]=\beta-\tau^2$$

$$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\frac{1}{1+X}\bigg]=\frac{1-\tau}{1+\tau}+\frac{\tau^2}{\beta}$$

Now consider $\lim{\tau\to0}$:

$$\lim_{\tau\to0}\mathbb{E}\bigg[\frac{1}{1+X}\bigg]=1$$

$$\lim_{\tau\to0}a=\beta$$

and $0<\beta<1$. So the upper bound can approach 1 for any value of $a$ ($0<a<1$).